# How to send updates from Service to an Activity

Tags: android, service, gps

I have ARSensorsService that extends Service and implements LocationListener ... How can I send the location updates "onLocationChanged()" to an Activity ?

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve this in two ways:

1. Either *Bind* your Service to Activity and employ **ResultReceiver** to get updates
2. Or broadcast intents (containing location updates) in Service and make use of **BroadcastReceiver** in your activity to listen to those broadcasted messages

Comment: I was able to do it using the Handler and Messenger classes as described [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#ownservice_messenger)

Comment: yes, Handler and Messenger can also help you instead of ResultReceiver